# How to access the range-step value within `toscalar()` statement used within `range()` statement

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, azure-analytics, kql

Am using a Kusto query to create a timechart within Azure AppInsights, to visualize when our webservice is within its SLO (and when it isn't) using one of [Google's examples of measuring if a webservice is within its error budget](https://landing.google.com/sre/workbook/chapters/slo-document/):

```
SLI = The proportion of sufficiently fast requests, as measured from the load balancer metrics. “Sufficiently fast” is defined as < 400 ms.
SLO = 90% of requests < 400 ms

Measured as:
count of http_requests with a duration less than or equal to "0.4" seconds
divided by count of all http_requests
```

Assuming 10-minute inspection intervals over a 7-day window, here is my code:

```
let fastResponseTimeMaxMs = 400.0;
let errorBudgetThresholdForFastResponseTime = 90.0;
//
let startTime = ago(7days);
let endTime = now();
let timeStep = 10m;
//
let timeRange = range InspectionTime from startTime to endTime step timeStep;
timeRange
    | extend RespTimeMax_ms = fastResponseTimeMaxMs
    | extend ActualCount = toscalar
    (
        requests
            | where timestamp > InspectionTime - timeStep
            | where timestamp <= InspectionTime
            | where success == "True"
            | where duration <= fastResponseTimeMaxMs
            | count 
    )
    | extend TotalCount = toscalar
    (
        requests 
            | where timestamp > InspectionTime - timeStep
            | where timestamp <= InspectionTime
            | where success == "True"
            | count
    )
    | extend Percentage = round(todecimal(ActualCount * 100) / todecimal(TotalCount), 2)
    | extend ErrorBudgetMinPercent = errorBudgetThresholdForFastResponseTime
    | extend InBudget = case(Percentage >= ErrorBudgetMinPercent, 1, 0)
```

Sample query output of what I wish to achieve:

```
InspectionTime [UTC]     RespTimeMax_ms  ActualCount  TotalCount  Percentage  ErrorBudgetMinPercent  InBudget
2019-05-23T21:53:17.894  400             8,098        8,138       99.51       90                     1  
2019-05-23T22:03:17.894  400             8,197        9,184       89.14       90                     0  
2019-05-23T22:13:17.894  400             8,002        8,555       93.54       90                     1
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
'where' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'InspectionTime'
```

I've tried `todatetime(InspectionTime)`, fails with same error.

Replacing `InspectionTime` with other objects of type `datetime` gets this code to execute OK, but not with the datetime values that I want. By example, using this snippet executes OK, when used within my code sample above:

```
   | extend ActualCount = toscalar
    (
        requests
            | where timestamp > startTime   // instead of 'InspectionTime - timeStep'
            | where timestamp <= endTime    // instead of 'InspectionTime'
            | where duration <= fastResponseTimeMaxMs
            | count   
    )
```

To me it seems that using `InspectionTime` within `toscalar(...)` is the crux of this problem, since I'm able to use `InspectionTime` within similar queries using `range(...)` that don't nest it within `toscalar(...)`.

**Note**: I don't want a timechart chart of `request.duration`, since that doesn't tell me if the count of requests above my threshold (400ms) exceed our error budget according to the formula defined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is invalid as you can't reference the `InspectionTime` column in the subquery that you're running in `toscalar()`.

if I understand your desired logic correctly, the following query might work or give you a different direction (if not - you may want to share a sample input dataset using the `datatable` operator, and specify the desired result that matches it)

```
let fastResponseTimeMaxMs = 400.0;
let errorBudgetThresholdForFastResponseTime = 90.0;
//
let startTime = ago(7days);
let endTime = now();
let timeStep = 10m;
//
requests
| where timestamp > startTime and timestamp < endTime
| where success == 'True'
| summarize TotalCount = count(), ActualCount = countif(duration <= fastResponseTimeMaxMs) by bin(timestamp, timeStep)
| extend Percentage = round(todecimal(ActualCount * 100) / todecimal(TotalCount), 2)
| extend ErrorBudgetMinPercent = errorBudgetThresholdForFastResponseTime
| extend InBudget = case(Percentage >= ErrorBudgetMinPercent, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Oh yes, you nailed it - thanks!
Can you recommend any sources where I can get a deeper understanding of Kusto (deeper than current [MS Kusto ref docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/)), to learn why I can't access `InspectionTime` within the subquery inside `toscalar()`?